# Module and controller in angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How do I use the module, controller and scope in angular dart. I'm trying to using angular dart but i don't know how to use it angular dart. if try to use @Controller it's showing error my angular dart version is 1.0.

```
 angular.module("users", ['commonerrors']);
```

How to use this line in AngularDart. i used the class for users and extend the module, how to declare the ['commonerrors'] in that module.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interesting to look at how it was implemented in [Angular Dart UI](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui) or look at [demo](http://akserg.github.io/angular.dart.ui.demo/index.html) site. I believe you will find answers on many of your questions there.

Angular Dart is not the same as AngularJS version 1.x and it doesn't use `angular.module()` statements to register new modules. Module registration happens via `addModule` method of `Application` class. To create new module you need do the following:

1. Create class `DemoModule` extends `Module` class;
2. Add dependencies to other modules through `install(new AngularUIModule())` method;
3. Register all components, decorators and other injectable classes in Dependency Injection via method of the same name `bind(TooltipDemo)`

Comment: thanks your reply,but i can't find the dependency widget injection in the module like angular.module("users", ['commonerrors'])